# AWS SDK Error - Signature not yet current

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, dreamhost

I'm using the `aws-sdk-php`, the SesClient specifically, i've deployed an app in a customer server (hosted in DreamHost) and I'm getting this error:

```
Signature not yet current: 20130909T170846Z is still later than 20130909T170823Z (20130909T170323Z + 5 min.)
```

I'm guessing the server time is misconfigured, I'm trying to reach DH support to check on that, i bet that will take a while.

Any other ideas? The app has been deployed many times before and i've never seen this error.

Comment: If someone is looking, here is an Amazon guide for dealing with the issue https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/system-clock-drift-ubuntu/

Comment: this link is no longer working. its broken.

Answer (score 61):

I had the similar issue. I was running my CI server from an Ubuntu EC2 instance and that has the time out of sync. I synchronised the time with NTP suing

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

It started working fine.

Comment: This works for Ubuntu servers on Digital Ocean as well.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using windows, just set the current time and time zone automatically. It will resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Works on Mac as well (System Preferences > Date & Time > Unlock in the bottom left > Check "set date and time automatically")

Comment: You also have to click on "Synchronize clock" (or something similar) below to make it work

Comment: Thanks! I was testing something by changing my time, didn't realize it could be the root cause.

Answer (score 10):

I just encountered the same problem with a Django app deployed to AWS. The site error was really vague, but the error log that was emailed to me said, "JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 403 Forbidden
{'message': 'Signature not yet current: 20150224T185106Z is still later than 20150224T185033Z (20150224T184533Z + 5 min.)'}" after a file path that pointed to Boto and Elastic Transcoder. Do the following on the server:

1. `ntpq -p` will tell you if you have ntp installed
2. If you don't have ntp, do `sudo apt-get install ntp`
3. `sudo service ntp stop`
4. `sudo ntpdate -s us.pool.ntp.org` will align your server's time with atomic clocks in the U.S. (this will need to be adjusted to your country)
5. `sudo service ntp start`

Good luck! You can read more here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html#configure_ntp

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue recently. I did the following

```
sudo ntpd -q -g
```

The `-g` option is needed if your clock is way out of sync. It forces `ntpd` to continue till it's in sync.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue and after some investigation, found the root cause.

Reason was that, my AWS instance/server timezone and my local system timezone from where i was making RESTful call were different. AWS assumes that request is also being made from the same timezone (it just ignore gap of 5 mins, not more than that). I was able to validate this by making test call from the AWS console and checking details in the logs (giving below Java snippet)

```
private String getDateString() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
    dfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  //server timezone
    return dfm.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to be sure the time of you server is 5 minutes accuracy from current time. check the AM or PM time.

Answer (score 2):

For windows , check your `time` and `timezone` is correct. Time of your PC must be `5 minutes` accuracy from current time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following for converting date to AWS request format.

```
String getAWSCompatibleDate() {
    var date = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyyMMddTHHmmss').format(date);
    var newDate = "$formattedDate" + "Z";
    print("Date - $date");
    print("New Date - $newDate");
    return newDate.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Centos6, check if the ntpd service is running.

service ntpd status
service ntpd start

it worked fine, after this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my laptop's time was not matching to my time zone when i made a sync between my laptop's time and time zone this error was gone and it started working fine