# AWS CloudWatch -- Signature Expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm setting up CloudWatch for several of my EC2 instances, using [AWS custom  CloudWatch metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts-perl.html).

Everything is going fine, except one of my instances gives me the below error:

> **ubuntu@my-host:~**$ /etc/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --disk-space-util --disk-path=/ --aws-credential-file=/etc/aws-scripts-mon/awscreds.template
>
> ERROR: Failed to call CloudWatch: HTTP 400. Message: Signature expired: 20150515T204709Z is now earlier than 20150515T204917Z (20150515T205417Z - **5 min**.)
>
> For more information, run 'mon-put-instance-data.pl --help'

I've tried searching around the Internet, including [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html), but no luck. Any ideas?

One hint:  I have a cron job  invoking this same command every 5 minutes. It is also unsuccessful. That may be related to the `x - 5 min.` message bit in the above error message.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww oops sorry about that. I've reposted this question/answer to [ServerFailt](http://serverfault.com/questions/693114/aws-cloudwatch-signature-expired), so feel free to close/delete this.

Comment: If someone is looking, here is an Amazon guide for dealing with the issue https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/system-clock-drift-ubuntu/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The system time of the problem EC2 instance is off by several minutes. See [AWS SDK Error - Signature not yet current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703486/aws-sdk-error-signature-not-yet-current)

This is likely the solution!

Comment: One of the solutions in the linked answer worked for me, I had to run `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` on my Ubuntu machine.