# AWS API gateway error: "message": "Signature expired: 20160917T171647Z is now earlier than 20160917T200334Z (20160917T200834Z - 5 min.)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created an API using AWS API gateway and deployed it following the steps similar to the tutorial for AWS API gateway. I Connected the API with AWS lambda function on the backend. Everything works fine from inside API gateway's test method but when I access the API from Postman, I get the following error
"message": "Signature expired: 20160917T171647Z is now earlier than 20160917T200334Z (20160917T200834Z - 5 min.)"
Searching on stackoverflow question
[AWS SDK Error - Signature not yet current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703486/aws-sdk-error-signature-not-yet-current)
says it may be a problem with system timing. As I am using AWS lambda and API gateway, I don't have control of the system time. What should I debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution. The error message is misleading. I was not accessing the full url to the API.

I was accessing something like
[https://**someChars**.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/](https://__someChars__.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/)
while the full url is
[https://**someChars**.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/**myUrlName**](https://__someChars__.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/__myUrlName__)