# InvalidSignatureException when try to use aws comprehend service using localhosted jupyter notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-iam

I am trying to use aws comprehend  service using my localhosted jupyter notebook instance installed on windows10

- I have created IAM user and get the access key and secret and add them to credentials file
- I have also add the values of access key and secret into my windows environment vaiables
- My code is as following

> ```
> comprehend = boto3.client('comprehend', region_name='us-west-2')
> phrases = comprehend.detect_key_phrases(Text=sample_review, LanguageCode='en')
> print('------- phrases ---------')
> for i in range(0, len(phrases['KeyPhrases'])):
>     print((phrases['KeyPhrases'][i]['Text']))
> ```

and I am getting the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClientError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-03a1f42b1c9e> in <module>
      2 comprehend = boto3.client('comprehend', region_name='us-west-2')
      3 # Key phrases
----> 4 phrases = comprehend.detect_key_phrases(Text=sample_review, LanguageCode='en')
      5 
      6 # Print the phrases:

c:\python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    355                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    356             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 357             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    358 
    359         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

c:\python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    674             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    675             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 676             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    677         else:
    678             return parsed_response

ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the DetectKeyPhrases operation: Signature not yet current: 20201126T001510Z is still later than 20201126T001452Z (20201126T000952Z + 5 min.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the solution of this post

[AWS SDK Error - Signature not yet current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703486/aws-sdk-error-signature-not-yet-current)

I found that my machine clock is not correct